# Why isn't my Facebook app publicly visable?

Tags: javascript, facebook, flash, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I have completed my Facebook application yesterday and users can't see it in Facebook search nor direct link. It just shows "page not found", so how to publish my application and make it public for all Facebook users?

P.S. : its working good with me and I can see it in [Dunes Lounge](http://apps.facebook.com/duneslounge/) and in developers app also.

Comment: Do you have sandbox mode enabled in the application settings?

Comment: Yesss, i used it to test without SSL certificate, i've to disable it to be public. Thanks Shan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may have sandbox mode enabled.